# openCypher client for AWS Neptune

Tags: amazon-neptune, graph-notebook, opencypher

I'm looking for a graph exploration tool similar to https://github.com/prabushitha/gremlin-visualizer for querying AWS Neptune while using openCypher to enjoy the new offering:
https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/database/announcing-opencypher-for-amazon-neptune-building-better-graph-applications-with-opencypher-and-gremlin-together/.
I'm familiar with the Jupyter notebook https://github.com/aws/graph-notebook but I'm looking for other alternatives.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With the recent release of openCypher on Neptune we have provided support for querying and visualizing results of openCypher queries via the Jupyter notebook as you have mentioned.  This tool is good for writing and visualizing queries but does not have graph exploration functionality for clicking on and expanding connected nodes/edges.

However with the release of openCypher Neptune supports interoperability between Gremlin and openCypher on top of the same data.  This means that you can load the data one time and use either query language.  This allows you to use any of the graph exploration tooling that works with Gremlin, such as https://github.com/prabushitha/gremlin-visualizer or https://www.tomsawyer.com/graph-database-browser to provide graph exploration capabilities without having to reload the data.

Comment: Thanks @bechbd. I'm aware I can still use the Gremlin tools, but we prefer using Cypher for querying and use one query language. The Neo4j explorer won't connect to Neptune, so I was wondering if there are any other alternatives. I guess there aren't much.

Comment: If you are looking for just graph exploration something like graphexp or gremlin visualizer allow you to do that without the need to write Gremlin.  If you want to see the results of queries then the graph-notebook provides that functionality.  However if you want to write a query and then explore out from the results of that query I'd agree there is not really much.